# get IEditorInput in xtext JavaValidator

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

I need to do some validation on my grammar based on the association of the file with a specific object I called MyResource. The command for opening the xtext editor is handled when user is right clicking on MyResource, hence I extended the FileEditorInput (called it MyEditorInput) and store the Myresource instance for the editor input there. However, I cannot get the instance of MyEditorInput in the MyGrammarJavaEditor code. I tried using `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput()`
assuming the validation is happening on the active editor, but this it throw NullPointerException. Do you know any ways to get the editor input in validator? Do you think my solution for associating an external object with the xtext editor/file/resource is correct? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The validation is executed by the Eclipse builder, too. That one is independent of any editors and checks the saved files in the project for consistency. I don't see any way to assume that the currently opened editor is the one that is attached to the currently validated resource.

Comment: What I am looking for is to get the EditorInput from validator and then check if this editor input is associated with the correct attribute or not. Sorry if the explanation is confusing.